# Nextion display - waveform time scale

Tags: arduino-uno, nextion

I've been working with Nextion display for a week.....I'm trying to build a small oscilloscope with the display and my Arduino UNO. I have used the waveform element to construct waveform of realtime voltage signal. What I wonder is if I can change the time scale of the Waveform displayed so that I can use a trigger circuit to display repeating signals look stationary as CROs and DSOs do......Anybody pls tell me if there is a way to increase the time scale of nextion waveform.

Thanks in Advance.....!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that that's not possible. The WaveForm-control is extremely simple as most of the other Nextion-controls. You might be able to achieve what you want with some trickery in your Arduino-code to clear and repopulate the data, but chances are that the display/control won't update fast enough.